# tabular: thicker lines

Tags: tables

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Foo} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Bar} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{BarA} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{BarB} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{FooA} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9\\ \cline{2-6}
& $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{FooB} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\ \cline{2-6}
& $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7&10 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

hi, how could I draw a thicker horizontal line between the lines of FooA and those of FooB and also a thicker vertical line between BarA and BarB?

I've tried many solutions found on the Web, but all of them cause some alignment error.

edit:
To clarify in the real table that I'm building I have many Foo columns (FooA, FooB, FooC,...) and many Bar rows (BarA, BarB, BarC,...). If the lines are all equals it's hard to tell to which Foo column and to which Bar row a number belongs. So I want to make thick lines to separate the Foo columns and the Bar rows.

Comment: duplicate [latex-tables-how-do-i-make-bold-horizontal-lines-typically-hline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/latex-tables-how-do-i-make-bold-horizontal-lines-typically-hline)

Comment: @RobertH No, the question you linked only refers to *horizontal lines* and is therefore merely related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In LaTeX you can do it with [`tabu`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841).  For the thickened `\cline` (which is now `\tabucline[1pt]{2-6}`) to not create a gap in the outer frame, one has to “undo” the vertical space added by the rule by annotating the preceding linebreak `\\[-1pt]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|[1pt]c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Foo} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Bar} \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|[1pt]}{BarA} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{BarB} \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{FooA} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9\\[-1pt] \tabucline[1pt]{2-6}
  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{FooB} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\[-1pt] \tabucline[1pt]{2-6}
  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7&10 \\
  \hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you don't want to use `tabu` (what I totally understand), then the [`boldline`](https://ctan.org/pkg/boldline) package might be for you.  It introduces the following rules

- `V{<factor>}` vertical rule which is `<factor>` thicker than the normal vertical rule.
- `\hlineB{<factor>}` horizontal rule which is `<factor>` thicker than the normal horizontal rule.
- `\clineB{<spec>}{<factor>}` horizontal rule which spans the columns given in `<spec>` and which is `<factor>` thicker than the normal horizontal rule.

To obtain a rule of `1pt` one has to replace two `|` by `V{2.5}` and the two `\cline` by `\clineB{2-6}{2.5}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boldline,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|cV{2.5}c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Foo} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Bar} \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{cV{2.5}}{BarA} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{BarB} \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{FooA} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9\\ \clineB{2-6}{2.5}
  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{FooB} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\ \clineB{2-6}{2.5}
  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7&10 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that works perfectly (I've tried the boldline solution)

Comment: @lambdauser Just an aside: I have updated all of your multicolumns because some rules were drawn twice.  For example, if you have a row which reads ``\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Foo} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Bar} \\``, then the right `|` of Foo is at the same position as the left `|` of Bar, which makes them overlap and appear thicker.  As a convention, I always leave out the left `|` in multicolumns (unless the multicolumn is the first column in a line, then we must not omit the left `|`).

Answer (score 2):

With ConTeXt MKIV and the custom frame extension by [[Aditya (2012)]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57006/10995)

```
\unprotect
\startuniqueMPgraphic {top_frame}
  draw topboundary OverlayBox 
    withpen pensquare scaled (\the\dimexpr\framedparameter{\c!top\c!rulethickness}\relax) 
    withcolor \MPcolor{\framedparameter{\c!top\c!framecolor}} ;

  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\startuniqueMPgraphic {left_frame}
  draw leftboundary OverlayBox 
    withpen pensquare scaled (\the\dimexpr\framedparameter{\c!left\c!rulethickness}\relax) 
    withcolor \MPcolor{\framedparameter{\c!left\c!framecolor}} ;

  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\installtopframerenderer{custom}{\uniqueMPgraphic{top_frame}}
\installleftframerenderer{custom}{\uniqueMPgraphic{left_frame}}

\setupframed
  [
    \c!top\c!rulethickness=\framedparameter\c!rulethickness,
    \c!top\c!framecolor=\framedparameter\c!framecolor,
    \c!left\c!rulethickness=\framedparameter\c!rulethickness,
    \c!left\c!framecolor=\framedparameter\c!framecolor,
  ]
\protect

\setupTABLE[option=stretch]
\setupTABLE[each][align={middle,lohi}]
\setupTABLE[column][5][leftframe=custom,leftrulethickness=2pt]
\setupTABLE[row][5][topframe=custom,toprulethickness=2pt]
\setupTABLE[row][7][topframe=custom,toprulethickness=2pt]
\starttext
\startTABLE
  \NC[nx=2] Foo  \NC[nx=4] Bar \NC\NR
  \NC[nx=2]      \NC[nx=2] BarA \NC[nx=2] BarB \NC\NR
  \NC[nx=2]      \NC $\lambda$ \NC $\theta$ \NC $\lambda$ \NC $\theta$ \NC\NR
  \NC[ny=2] FooA \NC $\mu$ \NC 2 \NC 3 \NC 8 \NC 9\NC\NR
                 \NC $\pi$ \NC 5 \NC 6 \NC 7 \NC 9 \NC\NR
  \NC[ny=2] FooB \NC $\mu$ \NC 2 \NC 3 \NC 8 \NC 9 \NC\NR
                 \NC $\pi$ \NC 5 \NC 6 \NC 7\NC 10 \NC\NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but I have to use it inside a latex project

Comment: This is not a hack but the proper way to interface metapost borders.

Comment: @Aditya I changed »hack« into »extension«.  Also, I found that the typo in `pack-fen.mkiv` (for which `\let\setinstalledframedimensions\pack_framed_overlay_initialize_indeed` was needed) is gone by now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I had the same problem some years ago and redefined the tabular line commands. I have not uploaded to ctan and I am not sure I consider it a finalized work. Still, I think it works. To try, save the following as `shtabularlines.sty`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Defines thick lines for use in tabular environments
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{shtabularlines}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Add an optional parameter for the line width to the command \hline,
%% \vline, and \cline:
%% 
%% \shhline[width]
%% \shvline[width]
%% \shcline[width]{c1-c2}
%% \shclinespace[width]
%% 
%% The default width is the same as standard lines. This is set by the
%% parameter \sharrayrulewidth. Reset with \renewcommand
%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\sharrayrulewidth{\arrayrulewidth}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% \hline
\def\shhline{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi%
  \@ifnextchar[{\sh@hline}{\sh@hline[\sharrayrulewidth]}}
\def\sh@hline[#1]{\hrule height #1 \futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
%% \vline
\def\shvline{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\sh@vline}{\sh@vline[\sharrayrulewidth]}}
\def\sh@vline[#1]{\vrule \@width #1}
%% \clinespace
\def\shclinespace{\omit%
  \@ifnextchar[{\sh@clinespace}{\sh@clinespace[\sharrayrulewidth]}}
\def\sh@clinespace[#1]{%
  \cr
  \hbox{\vrule height \arraystretch #1 width 0pt}
}
%% \cline
\def\shcline{\omit%
  \@ifnextchar[{\sh@cline}{\sh@cline[\sharrayrulewidth]}}
\def\sh@cline[#1]#2{\sh@@cline[#1]#2\@nil}
\def\sh@@cline[#1]#2-#3\@nil{%
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#3%
  \advance\@multicnt-#2%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip -#1}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\endinput
```

Then you can use it according to the (brief) manual below. If the quality is too poor you can get a better at [shtabularlines.pdf](http://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/home/hs.sho/Misc/shtabularlines.pdf).

[image]

As you can see my version of \cline has a problem since it does not set the space for the extra width. This is compensated by hand by `\shclinespace`.

So the following tabular environment gives the table below:

```
\renewcommand\sharrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c!{\shvline}c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Foo} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Bar} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c!{\shvline}}{BarA} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{BarB} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{FooA} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9\\ \shcline{2-6}\shclinespace[\sharrayrulewidth]
& $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{FooB} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\ \shcline{2-6}\shclinespace[\sharrayrulewidth]
& $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7&10 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it works almost perfectly but the vertical line is only partially drawn. It stops before BarA and BarB.

Comment: @Stefan The [`boldline`](https://ctan.org/pkg/boldline) package might actually be doing the same as your `shtabularlines` is trying to achieve.

Comment: @lambdauser Did you update the `\multicolumn` spec also? I have updated with a version that works. But it might be a good idea to have a look at `boldline` also as suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: yes it works after fixing the `\multicolumn` issue

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
      {
        letter = B,                   % lettre to use in the format 
        command = BoldHline ,         % command for horizontal rules
        width=1pt,                    % space reserved for the rule
        tikz = { line width = 1 pt }  % Tikz instruction for a rule of width 1 pt
      }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|cBc|c|}
\Hline
\Block{1-2}{Foo} && \Block{1-4}{Bar} \\
\Hline
\Block{1-2}{} && \Block{1-2}{BarA} && \Block{1-2}{BarB} \\
\Hline
\Block{1-2}{} && $\lambda$ & $\theta$ & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ \\ 
\Hline
\Block{2-1}{FooA} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\
\BoldHline 
                  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 \\
\Hline
\Block{2-1}{FooB} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\
\BoldHline
                  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 10 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

In fact, with `nicematrix`, you can also use the key `hvlines` to draw all the rules (excepted in the blocks created by the command `\Block`) and explicitly use the command `\BoldHline` and the specifier `B` where needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines]
\Block{1-2}{Foo} && \Block{1-4}{Bar} \\
\Block{1-2}{} && \Block{1-2}{BarA} && \Block{1-2}{BarB} \\
\Block{1-2}{} && $\lambda$ & $\theta$ & $\lambda$ & $\theta$ \\ 
\Block{2-1}{FooA} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\
                  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 9 \\
\Block{2-1}{FooB} & $\mu$ & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 \\
                  & $\pi$ & 5 & 6 & 7 & 10 \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [very thick] 
            (2-|5) -- (last-|5) 
            (5-|2) -- (5-|last) 
            (7-|2) -- (7-|last) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]